# Why NFS4 client is trying to contact portmap service?

Tags: debian, nfs4

After upgrading Debian from wheezy to stretch I have a problem with mounting nfs4 volume. Before the upgrade the client did not try to contact portmap service (port 111), and after the upgrade it tries to do that before anything else and fails (because it is blocked on the NFS server), so the whole mounting ends with connection timeout. I've verified it with tcpdump.

Any help would be appreciated.

Command:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o rw,nolock nfsserver:/path /mnt/path
```

or:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o rw,nolock,port=2049 nfsserver:/path /mnt/path
```

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
9.1

# uname -rv
3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.93-1

# dpkg-query -l | grep nfs-common
ii  nfs-common                       1:1.3.4-2.1
```

Comment: Based on https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s2-nfs-methodology-portmap.html  `portmap` was still used in NFSv2 and v3 as backward compatibility, so maybe it is the same case for NFSv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did the trick:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o rw,nolock,nfsvers=4,minorversion=1 nfsserver:/path /mnt/path
```